# cannot find type system.componentmodel.marshalbyvaluecomponent in module

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am creating Windows Store Apps for Windows 8 using VS2012 Premium.

There are no errors in any of the particular line of the code but when i am building the code I am getting an error of:

> *"Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent in
>   module System.dll"*

It doesn't specify exactly where the error is.

Comment: If you go to the Output window when you build, have a look at the precise error message there. Sometimes that has more information than the errors list. Please copy and paste the contents of that view into your question.

Comment: Also, please tell us more about your app - in particular, if you have references to any other libraries.

Comment: I am creating apps using the Project Server CSOM(Client-SideObjectModel) for Creating Project .

Comment: And you didn't think to mention that in the question? It's not clear to me that you can use that with Windows Store Apps at all.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a Windows Store app (VS 2015, UWP) and was trying out some tools when I got this same message. I tried doing a repair with no change. Next I uninstalled some of the tools/references that I had added previously. That did the trick. I realize that this may not help the OP as the question was posted two years ago, but hopefully someone else may benefit.